# nginx: doesn't a successful try_files finish the request without involving other location blocks?

Tags: nginx

What I'm trying to do is have a server block such that requests for my domain without a subdomain specified successfully serves any existing file with the uri prefix `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`, but gives a 404 for anything else.

```
    server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    # Satisfy acme verification for both ports 443 and 80
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/acme-challenges/;
        try_files $uri =404;
        return 200;
    }
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

What I'm finding is that if file `/usr/share/nginx/acme-challenges/foo` exists and is readable by the nginx process, then for request `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/foo`, `foo`gets downloaded successfully - but I get a 404 status code and the default nginx error page for it. Initially, I did not have the `return 200;` line after the `try_files` because I thought that if the `try_files` succeeded, no other location block would be involved. I tried adding that to "make sure" the  other location block would not execute, but it didn't help.

I'm sure the other location block is causing the 404, because if I change its contents to `return 200;` then I get the successful download and no body (whatever was displayed, e.g. the google home page remains in place when I type the request in the address bar).

I can't make any sense of this. The docs note that try_files can cause an internal redirect when a fallback uri is selected, but not when the initial file succeeds!

Comment: With more testing, I found that I could get what I want by deleting the `return 200` from the first location block, and deleting the second location block entirely. And surely that's the best thing to do since it's simpler. But I sure would like to understand why the config in the question behaved the way it did!

Comment: It would probably work correctly if you remove the `try_files` and `return 200` statements. `alias` and `try_files` have some strange [side-effects](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) and `return 200` is just plain strange.

Comment: @RichardSmith Well, I explained why I put the return 200 there, just to see if it made a difference; it wasn't there originally. And my comment noted that removing both that and the second location block seemed to work okay. But you have a interesting/good point in that the try_files (at least as written with a second argument of =404) doesn't seem to be useful since without the directive at all it would look for the uri under the root, and if not there issue a 404 by default.  But I think the "root" of the problem (related to the alias directive) is that I didn't have any root directive!

Comment: The choice of directory `/usr/share/nginx/acme-challenges` is also quite strange. Are you following some bizarre Internet tutorial, or possibly using a Debian-based distribution?

Comment: I don't know about bizarre, but I was more-or-less following [this](https://github.com/diafygi/acme-tiny#step-3-make-your-website-host-challenge-files). For our staging server, I don't want to pay for an SSL certificate, and the status of the myriad of really funky opaque wrappers for the letsencrypt acme server is mind-boggling. I picked acme-tiny because it 's simple enough to understand (sort of), and just generates the certificate with mucking with nginx configuration. We have a bunch of test servers on subdomains of a test domain.

Comment: Unlike the production domain, the bare domain without a subdomain doesn't redirect to www.domain, it just gives 404. The validation step of acme-tiny issues a request to every name in the csr. For the production site we use the named domain as the CN, with a SAN of www.domain. I wanted to do the same for letsencrypt, but verification was failing when it sent a request to the naked name. So I wanted to change nginx config to accept only the verification requests, but 404 everything else. The root is empty, verification requests access a tree outside it via alias. Does that make more sense, now?

Comment: Or maybe you meant the choice of /usr/share, which is generally intended to be read-onlyable. I don't actually know why/how that was chosen rather than /var. It's just where the htdocs directory was placed. This is on Amazon EC2 running Amazon Linux, where /usr and /var are both on the root filesystem, which has lots of space. I suppose it would make sense to move it to /var in preparation for growth.

Comment: I've just used certbot certonly, with a similar `location` that has a `root /var/www` (which corresponds to certbot's `-w /var/www` command line option and makes everything work).

Comment: I thought that certbot's dependencies and complexity were overwhelming - with no yum package for it on Amazon's AWS EC2 running Amazon Linux, it was a nightmare. acme-tiny was quite manageable. One thing it doesn't have is certificate renewal, but as far as I can tell just re-running acme-tiny with an 88-day cron job with the same csr file ought to work just fine. As I noted, the /usr/share placement was just an accident of the way I originally set up nginx a couple of years ago, I'll move that to /var before I button this stuff up.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. So my underlying problem is solved, but I don't really have a good answer as to why my original config didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the following would work:

```
location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge(/.+)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/acme-challenges;
    try_files $1 =404;
}
```

This way we avoid using `alias` with `try_files`. We simply capture the filename in `location` and use the captured filename in `try_files`.

Comment: If I can find the time, I can play with this just for fun. But as I said in comments above, `try_files` with a first argument that resolves to the desired pathname using the using the uri portion of the request (whether the full path is derived from a `root` directive or an `alias` directive), with a second and final argument of =404 is completely redundant, since that's the default behavior in the absence of the `try_files` anyway. My suspicion is that in my original config, I had no `root` directive at all, and if your config works it would be because it supplies a `root`...

Comment: Basically, `alias` "overrides" the `root` directive, so it's plausible that you'd get bad behavior if you had no `root` directive at all.